# Flutter error occurred while changing app icon in dart language

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling

While creating a flutter project everything was working good but i wanted to change my app icon so i added png file which was created on appicon.co and added in both ios and android folder but it showed error such as

> 

Launching main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
main.dart:1

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\flutter_learn_the_basics\lib\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.lib:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

> 

I added image file which was png in folder \lib\android\app\src\main\res in this i deleted existing folders named mipmap and added my mipmap folder which i got from website used to create icon

```
appicon.co
```

and after adding i run my code and it showed error
please help

Comment: Hi, have you tried using this library to change app icon: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons